# determining whether a set is dense in $\mathcal{C}(D,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, polynomials, metric-spaces

> Let $B$ be the closed unit disc $B = \overline{B}(0,1) = \{z\in \mathbb{Z} |\lVert z\rVert \leq 1\}$ in $\mathbb{C}.$ Determine whether the algebra $\mathcal{P} := \mathcal{P}(B,\mathbb{C})$ of polynomial functions $p:B\to\mathbb{C},$ where $p$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{C},$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}(B,\mathbb{C})$ under the supremum metric.

If the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is useful, I'd need to verify that $\mathcal{P}(B,\mathbb{C})$ separates points and vanishes nowhere and is closed under conjugation (since $B$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}$). The identity function $x\mapsto x$ is in $\mathcal{P}(B,\mathbb{C}),$ so it separates points. Also, $\mathcal{P}$ vanishes nowhere as the constant functions are in it. I just need to verify that $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under conjugation. But this is also clear as if $p:B\to \mathbb{C}$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{C},$ so does its conjugate.

> Am I doing something wrong and if so, **how can I fix it** to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is not valid because polynomials are not closed under conjugation. The function $f(z)=\overline z$ is continuous but it cannot be approximated uniformly by polynomials since it is not analytic. What you  are missing is the fact that your class consists of finite sums of the type $\sum a_kz^{k}$ and this does not include polynomials in $\overline z$.

More details: The following is a basic theroem in Complex Analysis:

If $G$ is an opne set in $\mathbb C$ and $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on $G$ converging uniformly on compact subsets of $G$  to a function $f$ then $f$ is holomorphic.

Corolloary: If $f_n$'s in above theorem are polynomials then the limit function is necessarily holomorphic.

Since $f(z)=\overline z$ is not analytic (in fact it is not differentiable at any point) it follows that this continuous function cannot be approximated uniformly by a sequence of  polynomials.

Comment: A polynomial on $B$ is defined as a finite sum of the type $\sum a_kz^{k}$ with coefficinets in $\mathbb C$. This is not closed under conjugation. On the other hand polynomials in real and imaginary parts of $z$  do satisfy then hypotheis of Stone-Weierstaras Theorem but in Complex Analysis  they are not called polynomials on $B$.  @Alfred

Comment: What makes you say that the conjugate of $\sum a_kz^{k}$ is $\sum \overline {a_k} z^{k}$? The conjugate is $\sum \overline {a_k} \, \, \overline z^{k}$. @Alfred

Comment: I have already answered the first question and I cannot make sense of your last part. @Alfred

Comment: sorry. Clearly just telling me whether I'm wrong or not is NOT very useful. I should've said I was expecting an answer; if I could solve the question myself I would've at least tagged it under proof-verification.

Comment: The conjugate of a $function$ $ f:B\to\Bbb C$ is $g:B\to\Bbb C$ where $g(x)=\overline {f(x)}$ for all $x\in B.$ The conjugate of a non-constant polynomial is not a polynomial.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for clarifying the stuff about conjugates. Can you verify whether my updated solution is correct? Honestly, the conjugate of a polynomial is just a definition, and knowing definitions only isn't really that helpful for getting a proof. But it's my fault I guess for not specifying that I wanted an "actual" answer for this question that doesn't just state whether I'm wrong or not just because of getting some definition wrong.

Comment: @Alfred Whay is $\frac 1 x$ a continuous function on the unit disk? It is not even defined there.  I have given a complete proof of the fact that your family is not dense. Do you have difficulty in understanding my proof?

Comment: @Alfred Kavi has already answered your question, with the statement "The function $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is continuous but it cannot be approximated uniformly by polynomials since it is not analytic."  If you do not understand why that solves your question, then the problem is with your understanding, not with the answer presented here.  If you would like a more detailed answer, you need to explain more thoroughly what your background is, what you know, and what you have tried (i.e. add more context to your question).

Comment: @Alfred I have added some details to my answer. If you have questions about the answer please let me know.

Comment: @Yly okay I guess the question has been answered, but honestly there's a much simpler approach that doesn't involve using analytic functions. And yes, the problem ***is*** with my understanding. But anyways, is the modified proof added to my answer correct?

Comment: @Alfred Your solution is also correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks!!